# How do I debug custom build processes in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfsbuild

I know my build isn't working, but I can't figure out how to debug it.  My only symptom is it only does a get operation for some of the projects in the solution. Setting verbosity to diagnostic tells me nothing, the event log is empty, what gives?

Under TFS 2008 using the barbaric tfsbuild.proj file, you could always execute your build locally and see what was happening.  Now, in TFS instead of bunch of spaghetti XML, we have a bunch of spaghetti XAML.  Is there a way to execute my build process template locally so I can see what is happening?

How do I debug custom build processes in TFS 2010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can checkout these steps [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/baruchf/archive/2009/07/02/debugging-team-build-now-you-can.aspx) regarding attaching the VS debugger to the TFSBuildServiceHost and debugging your build template.

Answer (score 4):

One way I used was using `WriteBuildError`, `WriteBuildMessage` and `WriteBuildWarning` activities. You can put them in several places in your build process template and check one of them gets executed.